# "Dont make it weird" - What does it mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, slang

[image]In the bathroom there is a sign "Get naked unless you are just visiting. Dont make it weird!". What does the last part ("Dont make it weird") mean? Dont act like it is weird ? Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what the whole sign means. I don't know whether it is a joke, irony, nonsense, or what it might mean if it is serious. It might help to know what kind of institution the bathroom is in (and is it a US bathroom, that probably doesn't have a bath, or a British one that does have a bath and might or might not have a toilet)?

Comment: @ColinFine Sorry, but bathrooms in houses/apts. in the US usually do have a bath[tub] and shower, often, together.

Comment: What's weird is telling some to "get naked" so, it is just a stupid joke.

Comment: @Lambie: but those don't often have signs in. I took it that this was in some sort of institution.

Comment: @ColinFine - Google shows you can buy posters, signs, and T-shirts with that slogan, incorporating a variety of animal pictures. Is it a 'meme', I wonder?

Comment: Yes, you are completely right, it is a "meme". A slogan on a poster in the bathroom in our neighbours apartment. I was told it is a joke. I would like to get the meaning of this joke.

Comment: As a meme it fails totally for me. Maybe there's a picture that points the reader in the right direction. As pure text … I'm totally lost. [BrE native.]

Comment: I have attached the discussed picture. Maybe, it will help.

Comment: … unfortunately, not in the slightest. I could try force several meanings from it… but I would never be certain I got the same one as the poster designer or current owner had anticipated.

Comment: It's actually pretty funny. Because what is weird is a cat in the bath saying that. As a poetical device, this is called **antiphrasis**. So, to tell the viewer and reader to not be weird is why it is funny.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think the image makes it any funnier or weirder, it's cute that's all. Online the image could be a cat, a dog, a mermaid or a young lady soaking in a bubblebath. Often the quote has no accompanying image but is written in a fetching fancy font. It belongs to the family of cliche signs: "Dance as if no one is watching" or "A house Is not a home until it has a cat”

Comment: @Mari-LouA Cats never like water. So, if the image were a person or dog, it would not be the same. And those two examples you give make sense on their face, this one doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a guest/visitor asks where the bathroom is, it's because they need to go to the loo, not to have a bath or a shower.

The sign is saying only if you are the owner of the home or someone staying overnight, should you get undressed and step into a bathtub.

It would be *weird* for a guest to get undressed in somebody's house.
It would be weird if anyone took a bath in a home they were not invited to stay in. It would be weird for any visitor to get naked for whatever reason… unless…

Another interpretation, which is probably closest, is the sign **telling anyone who is reading,  to get undressed** but only **if they are not** (*unless*) visiting.

It's what one might call a *[saucy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/saucy)* joke.

[image]

Comment: It is not the slogan that is funny. It's the visual clash between the cat in the bath and what is being said.

Comment: @Lambie  There are home signs with the same wording but without any images.